# Save From A Google Sheet to another Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a special education teacher and I'm trying to create a form to help me track accommodations for different students. I'm working on a Google Sheets App Script to save information from a Data Entry form to another Google Sheet. The information in sheet Accommodation Tracking should be saved to sheet Test Database when a Student has a check next to his/her name. All other information in sheet Accommodation Tracking should be placed under the correct header in Test Database.  True or False under each accommodation. Each checked student i.e. Student 33 should only appear once each time the sheet is submitted with all information saved under the correct row and heading in the Test Database Sheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Sample Accommodations Tracking Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFcA8.png)

[Corresponding Test Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfUgi.png)

Here is my current code.  Yes I'm new, but I'm trying hard to learn.

```
 function updateTestDatabase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var trackingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Accommodation Tracking");
  var databaseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test Database");
  
  var trackingData = trackingSheet.getRange("A12:A21").getValues();
  var trackingStatus = trackingSheet.getRange("B12:B21").getValues();
  var trackingDataD = trackingSheet.getRange("D12:D21").getValues();
  var trackingStatusD = trackingSheet.getRange("B13:B21").getValues();

  var databaseData = databaseSheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var databaseDataH = databaseSheet.getRange("H:H").getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < trackingData.length; i++) {
    if (trackingData[i][0] == true && trackingStatus[i][0] == true) {
      for (var j = 0; j < databaseData.length; j++) {
        if (databaseData[j][0] == "") {
          databaseSheet.getRange(j + 1, 1).setValue(trackingData[i][0]);
          databaseSheet.getRange(j + 1, 7).setValue(trackingStatus[i][0]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (var k = 0; k < trackingDataD.length; k++) {
    if (trackingDataD[k][0] == trackingData[k][0] && trackingStatusD[k][0] == true) {
      databaseSheet.getRange(k + 1, 8).setValue(trackingStatusD[k][0]);
    }
  }
}``
```

Here is the Test Database Page with sample data if you'd like to play around with it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-9ldjGhdtyOuXkydNuJTUxFkK20nq1n14pqIBevmXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: We are not a code writing service.  If you have specific questions about  the code feel free to ask them, otherwise plan to develop most of the code on your own.

Comment: Thanks Cooper, As I mentioned the code is located inside the apps scripts as it would do no good to post it individually because of the variables and functionality involved.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Yes but if I follow the link to your spreadsheet then I will have disclosed my email address to you and I prefer not to do that.   So if you wish my help you have to ask a proper question and post all of the information required into the question.

Comment: Thanks Cooper, I've updated the question with specifics and a sample code I've been working on.  It's been many, many years since I've coded anything, but I'm enjoying learning again :)

Comment: trackingStatusD and trackingDataD are not the same length.  Look at the ranges.

Comment: You should used ranges like "A1:A" with apps script try it this way instead `var databaseData = dsh.getRange("A1:A" + dsh.getLastRow()).getValues();`

Comment: It would be better for us if you can ask specific script related questions since we are not likely to have any application specific knowledge.